# How do I properly attribute code copied from Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, licensing

From my understanding, it's fine to copy Stack Overflow code so long as you fully understand it (so as to not copy vulnerabilities, etc). I am wondering what the proper way to attribute code is if I have copied it. Previously I have just added a comment with a URL to the source, but I also know that the site's content is licensed under CC BY-SA 4.0: https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/. I find the requirements a bit complicated (copywrite notice, license notice, disclaimer notice, ...). In practice, do I need all that for a small bit of code, or does a URL suffice?

Apologies if this is the wrong sort of question for Stack Overflow.

An example of the sort of credit expected under the license:

[Appropriate credit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ngzf.png)

Comment: You may find better answers at [opensource.se] or [law.se]

Comment: All content in posts here is licensed under the CC BY-SA license. The requirements are stated fairly succinctly in the Help Center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing and https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing. When using something you found on Stack Overflow in code, it is sufficient to include a comment in the code giving the name of the author (display name used on Stack Overflow) and a link (URL) back to the original content (use the "share" link under the post to get a short URL).

Comment: @CodyGray Is your first link relevant here since it is about using other work _in a SO post_?

Comment: @Bill Yes, I believe it is. It describes the CC BY-SA attribution/referencing requirements in a way that I think is very clear.